Check whether an event made a change in the appearance of certain words in a corpus
SCENARIO
I am studying a corpus of 100.000 academic papers written by students from the year 1980 to the year 2000. I think a specific event at the end of 1999 might have increased the usage of certain subject-specific terms. I have a list $A$ of 1000 words $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{1000}$ that I believe might have increased in usage and a list of $B$ of 1000 words $b_1, b_2, ..., b_{1000}$ that I extracted at random from the papers themselves. I made sure that all 2000 words appear at least once in a paper every year, and that they are all distinct, so there is no overlap within the lists and no overlap between them.
Ideally, I want to check that the words in A have increased "more than normally" in the year 2000. Comparing with B would help me check that the increase is not true for every word, and comparing with years before 1999 would allow me to check that such fluctuations are not common. However, I am limited by the kind of data I have. This scenario is quite contrived, so please bear with me.
Now, I don't have direct access to the papers, but I am able to use a search engine to scan in how many papers, for a given year, a word is present. Each year has a different number of papers; I know the number for each year.
EXAMPLE
The year 1980 has 4567 papers. For each word in both $A$ and $B$, I can extract the number of papers that have that word. Dividing it by 4567, I can easily calculate the proportion of papers where that word is present. So, for instance, I could tell you that $a_1$ is present in 3456 papers in 1980, and the proportion would be 3456/4567. Comparing the number of papers $a_1$ appears across year is not very meaningful since the number of papers changes year by year, but I can calculate the absolute and relative increase/decrease of the proportion of papers with $a_1$ in it from year to year.
QUESTION
Now, what kind of test I could run on the data I have for the words in $A$ to check that the increase I see in this statistic has been significant? My suspicion, and what I want to test, is a relative change in proportion for the words in A from 1999 to 2000 that I don't see in B or from the years before, i.e. from 1998 to 1999, from 1997 to 1998, etc. Just to recap, proportion is the fraction of papers with at least once the word in it, and relative here means that I weigh an increase from 2% to 4% much more than one from 50% to 55%.
Additional info:

Year after year, the percentage of papers with a word $w$ in it, regardless of whether $w$ is in $A$ or $B$, increases. So, anything like a contingency table won't really work: I never expect the proportion to be stable anyway. I could perhaps use the data from $B$ to estimate what the random increase every year is – the relative increase in the proportion of a word seem to be – but I am sure how to do this properly.
I cannot draw any additional data. Specifically, we cannot obtain the actual frequency of words (number of appearances of word/length of text). I understand this limits greatly the result.
I am perfectly okay with comparing year with year; I am not looking to do multi-year comparisons.

MY IDEA
Here is the best I could come up with: I can calculate the relative change in proportion-of-papers with a word $w$ for each of the 2000 words for 1999-2000 (e.g. a word going from 2% to 4% would receive a score of 200% change). Then, I compare the results between the words in $A$ and the ones in $B$ using a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test: if the big event in 1999 had an effect, I should detect two different distributions. Conversely, doing the same for each pair of years before 1999 should yield the opposite result (or, at least, much lower p-values).
Is this method sound? Do you have better solutions in mind? Is there a way to run a test that does not involve $B$?

Not a full answer, but I think the inclusion of word list B can help assess possible causation. If you see that words in A became more frequent after 1999, that might be attributable to the event you mention. But if words in B also became more frequent, it might suggest that papers are just getting longer and contain more words overall. Causation will be tricky in general - if you see changes in proportions it's not evidence the event was responsible. If you see no change, it's not directly evidence the event had no effect - maybe it had a large effect which was countered by something else.
